# Method to update related details record after the summary record is created

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement as below:

> 1. 20 detail records are inserted into detail table, which contain summary_id field which are not known at this time.
> 2. one summary record for the above 20 detail records need to be inserted into summary table.
> 3. Update the summary_id for the related summary record into 20 detail records.
>
> > My question: What is the best way to do step #3?

The difficulty is at how to get the batch of detail records related to current summary record, especially `parallel` execution needs to be supported for different batch of (1,2,3).

A sql fiddle is created: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ddd13